# Why are python dictionaries not reversible for python3.7?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Starting from 3.7, standard python dictionaries are guaranteed to maintain the insertion order. (*)

```
d = {'b': 1, 'a': 2}
for k in d: 
    print(k)
# Prints always 'b' before 'a'.
```

In other words, the dict keys are kept in a strict order. In principle, this would allow the keys to be reversible. However, none of the following works:

```
# TypeError: 'dict' object is not reversible
for k in reversed(d): 
    print(k)

# TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not reversible
for k in reversed(d.keys()): 
    print(k)
```

**Questions:** What is the reasoning behind this behavior? Why have dicts not been made reversible? Are there any plans to change this behavior in future?

The workaround of course works:

```
for k in reversed(list(d.keys())): 
    print(k)
```

(*) As a matter of fact, this is the case already for typical installations of python 3.6, as discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537308/3388962).

---

**Update**: Starting with [python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html) dicts are actually reversible. The accepted answer refers to the discussion between Guido and other core developers that led to this decision. In a nutshell, they weighted language consistency against implementation efforts and actual benefits for the users.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#reversed):

> **reversed**(*seq*)
>
> Return a reverse `iterator`. seq must be an object which has a `__reversed__()` method or supports the sequence protocol (the `__len__()` method and the `__getitem__()` method with integer arguments starting at 0).

A `dict` object doesn't implement `__reversed__`. It does implement both of the latter methods. However, `__getitem__` takes keys as arguments, rather than integers (starting at 0).

As to why, this has already been suggested and discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dev-python/76kIoAEKlew).

**EDIT:**

These quotes are from [Python-Dev mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dev-python/76kIoAEKlew) (thread "Add __reversed__ methods for dict", started on 25. 05. 18), I'll start with the "conceptual" arguments, first one is from Antoine Pitrou:

> It's worth nothing that OrderedDict already supports reversed().
>   The argument could go both ways:
>
> 1. dict is similar to OrderedDict nowadays, so it should support
>      reversed() too;
> 2. you can use OrderedDict to signal explicitly that you care about
>      ordering; no need to add anything to dict.
>
> My thought is that guaranteed insertion order for regular dicts is brand new, so it will take a while for the notion settle in and become part of everyday thinking about dicts.  Once that happens, it is probably inevitable that use cases will emerge and that __reversed__ will get added at some point.  The implementation seems straightforward and it isn't much of a conceptual leap to expect that a finite ordered collection would be reversible.

Followed by Raymond Hettinger's reply:

> Given that dicts now track insertion order, it seems reasonable to want to know the most recent insertions (i.e. looping over the most recently added tasks in a task dict).  Other possible use cases will likely correspond to how we use the Unix tail command.
>
> If those use cases arise, it would be nice for __reversed__ to already be supported so that people won't be tempted to implement an ugly workaround using popitem() calls followed by reinsertions.

The main concern expressed in the mailing list *was* that this would add too much bloat or reduce memory efficiency (having to have doubly linked lists instead of singly linked ones) in at least some implementations, here's Inada Naoki's quote from Python bug tracker ([issue 33462](https://bugs.python.org/issue33462)):

> "Have an order" doesn't mean "reversible".  For example, single linked list is ordered, but not reversible.
>
> While CPython implementation can provide efficient `__reverse__`, adding `__reverse__` means **all** Python implementation is expected to provide it.
>   For example, some Python implementation may be able to implement dict with hashmap + single linked list.  If `__reverse__` is added, it's not possible anymore.

Back to the mailing list, here are the two last messages (both posted on 08.06.2018). First is from Michael Selik:

> Am I correct in saying that the consensus is +1 for inclusion in v3.8?
>
> The last point in the thread was INADA Naoki researching various implementations and deciding that it's OK to include this feature in 3.8. As I understand it, Guido was in agreement with INADA's advice to wait for MicroPython's implementation of v3.7. Since INADA has changed minds, I'm guessing it's all in favor?

Concluding with Guido van Rossum's message:

> That sounds right to me. We will then have had two versions where this was the case:
>
> - 3.6 where order preserving was implemented in CPython but in the language spec
> - 3.7 where it was also added to the language spec

As noted in the other answer and comments, `reversed()` is supported for both dicts and dictviews since version 3.8 (14.10.2018).

Comment: Your second quote seems like a bias selection from that thread. The consensus seems to be that the functionality will be added in 3.8. Also prior to python 3.7 there simply was no ordering on a normal `dict` object (at least not guaranteed from the language) so `reversed` also made no sense

Comment: I don't have a dog in the fight, I just quoted his first response. But you're right, point well taken - I removed the quote.

Comment: Thanks. The discussion thread of the python-dev was revealing. As a matter of fact, the feature already has been implemented in python 3.8, which was released just two days ago (October 14 2019).

Comment: [Since python 3.8 reverse() is usable on dicts](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html)

Comment: The docs quote is not helpful, it only begs the next question "so, why doesn't the dict type implement `__reversed__`"?  The python-dev link has useful content, but the relevant parts should be reproduced in the answer directly (since such off-site links tend to rot).

Comment: @wim I left the original answer as it was, but I did try to pick out the relevant parts for archiving and add them to the answer. Feel free to edit the question to add/remove quotes to better preserve the useful content.

Answer (score 3):

[Since python 3.8 reverse() is useable on dicts](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html)

> Dict and dictviews are now iterable in reversed insertion order using reversed(). (
>   Contributed by Rémi Lapeyre in bpo-33462.)

Answer (score 3):

**Update for python 3.8**

Dict and dictviews are now iterable in reversed insertion order using reversed()

```
>>> dict = {1: "1", 2: "2", 3: "3"}
>>> reversed(dict)
<dict_reversekeyiterator object at 0x7f72ca795130>
```

Comment: Does this answer contribute anything new that is not already covered by other answers, comments or the question itself?

Comment: @normanius It has a lil visual code sample, might be helpful for the quick browser

Comment: py3.8 TypeError: 'dict' object is not reversible